# RabbitMQ - posting message via MQTT doesn't publish message in exchange

Tags: rabbitmq, mqtt

I have rabbitmq with mqtt plugin enabled.

I have created publisher and subscriber in python and both seems to work.
My problem is that this messages doesn't appear in queue that I set up.

In rabbitmq I have

1. set up queue lets say `mqtt-messages`.
2. binded this queue in `amq.topic` exchange with `test` as routing key.

Then I'm trying to publish message on topic `test` which should be routed to `mqtt-messages`

When I publish message via rabbitmq management, those messages are propagated to queue but when I do it via my python script those messages appear in mqtt topics but not in queue. Those messages does not even appear as `unroutable`. They just don't exist outside of mqtt topics.

Comment: Same problem here. Any solution?

Comment: Yeah same here when subscribing. MQTT just creates a new queue no matter what